# How to work with multiple pages or forms

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to create one window and on that window I would have a toolbar with different buttons.

When I go to click on one of the buttons It would display something like information about a person or when I click on another button It would  display some other information about employees.

How can I do this. Can I make add pages and then insert that page onto a grid or panel when that button calls for it?

Or   Should I just make multiple panels and create them all on one window(but if I do this how would it be easy for me to edit each of those panels when they are stacked on one another all in one window). I hope I'm being clear about this, Idk how else to ask this question. Any help is appreciated.

Also how do I dock something so that it resizes itself when maximize or minimize?

Answer (score 3):

One way is to create another form and open it from a button event:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Show();
    }
}
```

If you want everything in one window, you can create a user control and add it to the first window:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl1 control = new UserControl1();
        control.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Controls.Add(control);
    }
}
```

Another option is using child forms:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.IsMdiContainer = true;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.MdiParent = this;
        form2.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea this can work but I'm dont want to have a new window pop up. I'm trying to keep everything in one window. Almost like tabControl but creating my own tab system with a toolbar and all.

Comment: A user control is a collection of controls you put together, and can reuse anywhere like any other standard control. You can off course use panels and handle them just the same (in the 2nd example replace UserControl with Panel). Putiting it all in a userControl makes it easier to manage, as you don't have to declare each panel and its components in your main form.

Answer (score 3):

Create a panel for each button you have. Then:

```
panelx.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; //this will fill the window.
```

And put all you want to show for that button on that panel.

When you want to show, say panel2 instead of panel1:

```
panel1.Hide();
panel2.Show();
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned earlier, this can be achieved using a tab control.

```
      public ParentForm()
    {
        TabControl tabcontrol1 = new TabControl();
        tabcontrol1.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        TabPage tab1 = new TabPage("Form1 Name");
        Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
        frm1.TopLevel = false;
        frm1.Parent = tab1;
        frm1.Visible = true;
        tabcontrol1.TabPages.Add(tab1);

        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        TabPage tab2 = new TabPage("Form2 Name");
        frm2.TopLevel = false;
        frm2.Parent = discotab;
        frm2.Visible = true;
        tabcontrol1.TabPages.Add(discotab);
    }
```

Using "stacked" custom user controls

```
    public ParentForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyUserControl1 control1 = new MyUserControl1();
        control1.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
        control1.BringToFront();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyUserControl2 control2 = new MyUserControl2();
        control2.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
        control2.BringToFront();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a "paged options" dialog box in Windows Forms a while ago. My blog post about it is here: http://www.differentpla.net/content/2004/10/implementing-a-paged-options-dialog (the images are missing, though).

Comment: If I add a page to my project and then put info like datagrids and listviews on there ect..How can display that page in the mainwindow when I click on a button or better you don't have to tell me how but if that can be done or not